# windows 7 adb driver Samsung galaxy S3

Tags: android, adb

For app development purposes, I would like to access Samsung Galaxy S3 (ICS) phone through ADB interface on my Windows 7 32 bit laptop. Where can I find the ADB driver for the phone?

Comment: what phone provider? t-mobile Galaxy S3 drivers are here http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201110/20111012041540182/T-Mobile_t989_GSII_ADB_Drivers.zip

Comment: Thank you apesa! The driver downloaded from the link worked for Verizon too.

Answer (score 20):

this worked for me. download the driver from:

http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Android-USB-Driver-for-Windows

Answer (score 4):

> adb shell --> 
>     'error: device not found'

Here is what worked for me with Win7 64 bits

1. Install from http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows

   - Note: This (in 2014) - may need other drivers for other OS
2. Open Device Manager | Other Devices | Smasung (yellow question mark)
3. Right Click | Update Driver Software ...
4. Browse my computer for driver software + Next
5. Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer
6. Select from the list Samsung Mobile driver

   Result: Device Manager doesn't show the phone under Other Devices, but instead display it under SAMSUNG Android Phone --> now can connect
7. Refresh: Try also to refresh adb by killing adb.exe process and adb shell again.

Comment: Thanks! But steps 2-6 weren't necessary. As I connected my Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android 4.3) to a computer (Windows 7 x64), the system found and installed the drivers automatically.