# ADB issues on Galaxy S3 and Windows 7 - installed but not working?

Tags: android, adb, windows-7-x64, galaxy

I'm trying to develop for my Galaxy S3 using my Lenovo U510 Ultrabook with Windows 7 64 bit. I have tried the following tutorials and then some:

http://www.dkszone.net/setup-install-adb-android-debug-bridge-windows-7
[windows 7 adb driver Samsung galaxy S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570284/windows-7-adb-drvier-samsung-galaxy-s3)

My phone is being listed as an ADB device in the Device Manager:
[image: Seems to be installed]

but when I run "adb devices" from the command prompt, I get the following:
[image: unauthorized!]

And nothing shows up in my AVD Manager:
[image]

I've tried this same thing with several different drivers and cables, and get the same results. Any ideas as to what's going on?

Thanks for any pushes in the right direction.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a tablet I tried to get up and running on Windows. See if your device has alternate connection options. On my tablet, I had to change my connection from `MTP` to `Ethernet` (which doesn't make sense, but oh well!)

Comment: Hm, that's one thing I forgot to mention, actually. I set it up in Developer Settings to use Debug Mode when connected, but that doesn't show up as an option when plugged in. Only MTP and PTP (camera).

Comment: Okay, after changing to PTP, Eclipse recognizes my phone and it is listed as a device when running "adb devices." However, attempting to upload an app results in a timeout:

[2015-06-10 23:53:03 - Hello World-android] Failed to install Hello World-android.apk on device '7d07527b': timeout
[2015-06-10 23:53:03 - Hello World-android] Launch canceled!

I remember there previously being a "Debug Mode" option that showed up upon plugging USB in on an older phone. Is that no longer a thing, or is that the missing puzzle piece here?